# python interceptor to intercept request coming in an end point

Tags: python, python-3.x, interceptor, web-frameworks

I am trying to implement an interceptor to intercept request coming in an end point. In this interceptor, I need to access headers before applying function. This interceptor should work with flask, django or any other frame work. Here I have written an example interceptor which is dependent on flask. Can any body suggest me how can I make it generic so that it can run with any web framework?

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, jsonify
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)

def interceptor2(func):
    print('this is executed at function definition time (def my_func)')

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('this is executed before function call interceptor')
        print(request.headers)   # accessing Headers                  request from flask, making this code dependent on flask
        # print(**kwargs)
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('this is executed after function call interceptor')
        return result

    return wrapper

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@interceptor2
def hello():
    # print(request.headers)
    return make_response(jsonify({'resp': " ok done"}), 200)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run('127.0.0.1', '5000', debug=True)
```

How can I write generic interceptor which can run with any web framework?